# What is the name of this style of configuration file?

Tags: configuration-files

What is the name of this type of configuration file, where sections are noted in square brackets and parameters are specfied with name/value pairs?

```
[section1]
n = 1

[section2]
s = foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the format for an old-style [`.INI` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). From the article:

> In MS-DOS and 16-bit Windows platforms up through Windows ME, the INI file served as the primary mechanism to configure operating system and installed applications features, such as device drivers, fonts, startup launchers, and things that needed to be initialized in booting Windows. INI files were also generally used by applications to store their individual settings.

Comment: Great, now I can as my real question about an INI parser for Python.